# How to use values-land with configChanges=orientation

Tags: android

Is there a way to have

```
  android:configChanges="orientation"
```

and also update the android style on rotation to use the values in values-land when the user rotates to landscape?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration config) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(config);

    if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        //changes in code for landscape
    } else if (config.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT){
        //changes in code for portrait
    }
}
```

Also you can create layout for landscape / portrait mode for single activity

```
res/layout: portrait

res/layout-land: landscape
```

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an easy way to do this I've found.  I ended up just manually updating the style as the other answer suggested.